# I can't get django fieldsets to work right

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model Spell

```
class Spell(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    spell_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
    spell_level = models.IntegerField()
    casting_time = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    casting_range = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    verbal = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    somatic = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    classes = models.ManyToManyField('PlayerClass', related_name='spells', blank=True)
    description = HTMLField()
```

and i have put this admin class in my admin.py

```
class SpellAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'spell_type', 'casting_time', 'casting_range', 
             ('verbal', 'somatic', 'material'), 
             'duration', 'classes', 'description')
```

But verbal, somatic and material don't show up on the same line in the admin add or change form.  As far as i can tell i've set everything up [like the docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields). I'm using django 1.9.6. Does anyone have an idea what piece i've done wrong or left out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied and pasted your code into a Django 1.9.6 project and it works exactly as the documentation argues.  The three fields `verbal`, `somatic` and `material` appear on the same line.

Django makes the line by adding a `div` with `class="form-row field-verbal field-somatic field-material"` and inside three `div`s with `class="field-box field-verbal"`.  It appears as follows:

```
<div class="form-row field-verbal field-somatic field-material">
     <div class="field-box field-verbal">
         <input checked="checked" id="id_verbal" name="verbal" type="checkbox"><label class="vCheckboxLabel" for="id_verbal">Verbal</label>
     </div>
     <div class="field-box field-somatic">
          <input id="id_somatic" name="somatic" type="checkbox"><label class="vCheckboxLabel inline" for="id_somatic">Somatic</label>   
     </div>
     <div class="field-box field-material">
          <label class="inline" for="id_material">Material:</label>
          <input class="vTextField" id="id_material" maxlength="255" name="material" type="text">
     </div>
</div>
```

That makes for the correct behaviour even if I reduce the browser window.

I suspect that you added in your `admin.py`

```
admin.site.register(models.Spell)
```

instead of

```
admin.site.register(models.Spell, SpellAdmin)
```

And your `ModelAdmin` was never picked up by Django, and, therefore, never used for rendering.

Comment: That was it, this my first time using admin classes, I didn't even think about registering it.